# Change form renderer template depending on Bundle

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Symfony ships with a form template inside `form_div_layout.html.twig` file. I want to change that template depending on the Bundle.

- Views inside Bundle A --> Show forms using `form_div_layout.html.twig`
- Views inside Bundle B --> Show forms using `form_div_whatever_layout.html.twig`

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in general. But, there is one way to do it in case you have only one form per page:

<kbd>template_a.html.twig</kbd>

```
{% if form|defined %}
    {% form_theme form "form_div_layout.html.twig" %}
{% endif}

{# rest of the tempalte goes here %}
```

<kbd>Every page in BundleA</kbd>

```
{% extends "....template_a.html.twig %}

{# extend the blocks defined in template_a.html.twig
```

Main drawback is that, if you have form, you have to pass it to template with variable name **`form`**, otherwise it won't work...

Maybe someone else can shine some more light on this subject...

Comment: That works for me. I suppose there is no way to iterate over form objects and apply themes to all of them. Thanks